# Haskell prelude generic functions out of scope

Tags: haskell

When trying to use what are called "generic" list functions in the Haskell prelude, I get an out of scope error - for instance when trying to use genericDrop, genericTake and so on.

Perhaps I need to import a module or something (but I can see no mention of that in the [prelude docs](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/7.8.3/docs/html/libraries/base-4.7.0.1/Data-List.html#v:drop) or by googling)

Comment: You can see all the names exposed by a module with `:browse Module` in `ghci`. To see what's in the prelude (ie that you don't need to import), you can do `:browse Prelude`.

Comment: A slight misconception here: `genericDrop` and `genericTake` are not in the prelude, which is why you need to import them.

Comment: Yeah I guess I thought since the Prelude includes some of Data.List and the like, it would include all of it

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, I believe you need:

```
import Data.List
```

In general, when I need to figure out which module to import, I find that [hoogle](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/) is very useful.  You can search for a particular function, and it will take you to hackage, which then will have the module the function belongs to at the top of the page.  For example, here is the result of searching for [`genericDrop`](https://www.haskell.org/hoogle/?hoogle=genericDrop) and the [associated hackage page](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/base/latest/doc/html/Data-List.html#v:genericDrop).

Comment: So some of the functions in Data.List can be used without importing it, but others need an import?

Comment: Yeah, some of the list functions are imported though the prelude.  In general, if you need list functions, I would import them through Data.List.  I also prefer when you explicitly specify which functions you are importing.  So for example, I would do `import Data.List(genericDrop)`, which will only import the one function.  This way it is easy to tell where things are coming from.

Comment: Ok yeah and you can tell from [here](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.1.0/docs/Prelude.html) which are imported through the prelude.. cheers